# Iterate through layered objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like this:

```
var shoppers = {
  "Bob": {favoriteApple: "Honeycrisp"},
  "Sue": {favoriteApple: "Braeburn"},
  "Derek": {favoriteApple: "Honeycrisp"}
}
```

I want to iterate through this object and count how many people prefer each kind of apple. How can I do this?

On a related note, why does this log as `undefined` three times instead of logging the actual apple name?

```
for (var person in shoppers) {
    console.log(person.favoriteApple); // undefined
}
```

Comment: `console.log(person.favoriteApple);` ==> `console.log(shoppers[person].favoriteApple);`

Comment: @Tushar Awesome, that works. I tried shoppers.person.favoriteApple, which I thought was the same. Why is it different?

Comment: @Tushar: This is not guaranteed to work, and should not be encouraged. Either test for `hasOwnProperty` for each index yielded by `foreach`, or iterate over `Object.keys(shoppers)` instead of over `shoppers`.

Comment: @JacobCrofts `shoppers.person` tries to find the `person` key in the `shoppers` object, which does not exists so returns `undefined`. Whereas `shoppers[person]` will first get the value of `person` and replace it and then finds it in `shoppers` object.

Comment: @Amadan You're right. I was just explaining what OP is doing wrong. Added the same in answer. Thanks.

Comment: So I guess the main issue here was me not understanding dot vs. bracket notation and how they aren't always interchangeable. It makes sense to me now. Thanks for your help. @Tushar

Answer (score 2):

You can use following

1. Iterate over the keys of main object by using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
2. Create an empty object to store the various items with count
3. Inside loop, check if the item is already present in the countObj, if yes then increment the count, else set the count as 1

```js
var shoppers = {
  "Bob": {
    favoriteApple: "Honeycrisp"
  },
  "Sue": {
    favoriteApple: "Braeburn"
  },
  "Derek": {
    favoriteApple: "Honeycrisp"
  }
};

// Create empty object to store item count
var countObj = {};

// Get the array of keys in object using `Object.keys`
// Iterate over keys array using `forEach`
Object.keys(shoppers).forEach(function(key) {
  // Get the value of favoriteApple
  var favApple = shoppers[key].favoriteApple;

  // If count exists, increment it else add count as 1
  countObj[favApple] = countObj[favApple] ? countObj[favApple] + 1 : 1;
});

console.log(countObj);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(countObj, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

---

Regarding the second question

> why does `console.log(person.favoriteApple);` log as undefined three times instead of logging the actual apple name?

```
for (var person in shoppers) {
    console.log(person.favoriteApple);
}
```

`person` in the `for` is the key of the object `shoppers`. To access the actual value of the key use `shoppers[person]`.

**Code:**

```
for (var key in shoppers) {
    // To stop showing the inherited/prototyped properties
    if (shoppers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(shoppers[key].favoriteApple);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
for (var prop in obj)
```

It iterates over **keys** of this object. So, in your case `person` will be `Bob`, `Sue`, `Derek`.

All you need is to use this key to access a value of a property:

```
for (var person in shoppers)
{
    console.log(shoppers[person]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can keep a tally like so:

```
var favoriteApples = {};
for(var name in shoppers) {
  var person = shoppers[name];
  if(!favoriteApples[person.favoriteApple]) {
    favoriteApples[person.favoriteApple] = 1;
  }else{
    favoriteApples[person.favoriteApple]++;
  }
}

console.log(favoriteApples);
// prints Object {Honeycrisp: 2, Braeburn: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var shoppers = {
  "Bob": {favoriteApple: "Honeycrisp"},
  "Sue": {favoriteApple: "Braeburn"},
  "Derek": {favoriteApple: "Honeycrisp"}
}

$.each(shoppers,function(key,val){
  console.log(key);
  $.each(val,function(k,v){
    console.log(k + "    "  + v)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```